# Passing data between ThreadPool threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, miniprofiler

I have a C# webserver which I have been profiling using the StackOverflow miniprofiler.  Because it's not an ASP.NET server, but each request was typically executed on its own thread, I rigged the miniprofiler to use `ThreadStatic` storage to track all of the profilers of an incoming request from start to finish.  This worked well.

Recently we've converted everything to use `async/await`, which means continuations after an `await` typically don't come back onto the same `Thread` and thus the `ThreadStatic` storage no longer works.

What's the best way to pass some small piece of data between different `ThreadPool` threads in this case?  Are there existing `SynchronizationContext` implementations that would be useful for something like this?

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that.  I'm working with 4.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's the best way to pass some small piece of data between different ThreadPool threads in this case?

Using the logical call context via the [`CallContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It exposes two static methods: [`LogicalSetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalsetdata(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`LogicalGetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalgetdata.aspx). The call context is stored and marshaled via the `ExecutionContext`, which is also in charge of the sync context, etc.

Using this class has two restrictions:

1. You're limited to the use of .NET 4.5 and above
2. Logical call context uses copy-on-write semantics, and performs a *shallow copy* once the data is mutated. This means you should only be using immutable data, as the references may be shared across multiple threads.

One last thing to note is `CallContext` is initialized only once you call it. This means that when using it, you're taking on some overhead because of the copy-on-write.

More on that can be found in a post by Stephan Cleary called [*Implicit Async Context*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the shallow copy and immutable data requirement.